# One key and two values (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am trying to merge a javascript array, these have a common value and share the index

for example

```
object A - ["name a", "value a"]
object B - ["value a", "value extension a"]
```

and both are separate objects

how do i combine, such that i get 
["name a", "value a", "value extention a"]

if we notice there are three values in the row, possibly 'name a' is the key

Any guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: The result you are trying to get is no a valid object because it does not have key: value signature. Are you trying to get array?

Comment: "a javascript array" (singular), "these" (plural). "these have a common value and share the index" (in example, common value does not have the same index). In the original post, the example was syntactically invalid. It continues like this, and i am therefore not willing to actually figure out what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use set for this.

```js
let objectA = ["name a", "value a"]
let objectB = ["value a", "value extension a"]

let result = new Set([...objectA, ...objectB]);


console.log(Array.from(result));
```

> `name a` is not a key it's value, array indexes are integer and start from `0`;